# C# min from datatable row

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with 6 columns, and I have to find the minimum value, for each row. How can this be done?

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Min
45   41   24   25   74   145  24
27   28   398  82   2    54   2
5   563    7   20   43   254  5
```

Comment: -1. Not showing any effort at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    result.Add(row.ItemArray.Cast<int>().Min());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => row.ItemArray.Cast<int>().Min());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataTable.Select(row => Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(row.Col1, row.Col2), row.Col3), row.Col4), row.Col5), row.Col6));
```

or

```
dataTable.Select(row => new int[] { row.Col1, row.Col2, row.Col3, row.Col4, row.Col5, row.Col6 }).Select(intArray => intArray.Min());
```

or shortend:

```
dataTable.Select(row => (new int[] { row.Col1, row.Col2, row.Col3, row.Col4, row.Col5, row.Col6 }).Min()));
```

or

```
dataTable.Select(row => row.ItemArray.Cast<int>().Min());
```

or if your dataTable contains other columns that aren't ints:

```
dataTable.Select(row => row.ItemArray.OfType<int>().Min());
```